# Set Authorization header in Laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel, http-headers, superagent

I have a laravel backend and a website on react/redux. I'm trying to pass my JWT token on a specific url from my frontend using [superagent-bluebird-promis](https://github.com/KyleAMathews/superagent-bluebird-promise)e but I keep getting

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

error. I have looked at every single article but couldn't figure it out.
Here is the code on my frontend:

```
import request from 'superagent-bluebird-promise'
......
requestPromise= request.get(API_URL + action.url);
      if(action.token)
        requestPromise.set("Authorization","Bearer "+ action.token).withCredentials();

    requestPromise.query({ // add query (if get)
      ...action.data,
    });
```

On my laravel I have this .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
RewriteRule .* - [e=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

and I also have a CORS middleware to allow this header which it never gets to here for this code to run:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{    
        $origin = 'https://mywebsite.com';


    return $next($request)
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', $origin)
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS')
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers','Authorization')
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials','true');
    ;
}
```

I'm also running my laravel in a docker/nginx setting if helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue by adding my cors middleware to global middleware in kernel.php

```
 protected $middleware = [
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\Cors::class,
];
```